# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que este menú ocupe todo el ancho de la página?

Tags: css

Este código me lo dió mi profesor de Informática para empezar a crear una página web, he probado con cambiar el valor de **widht** a 100% pero lo único que hace es cambiar de posición el menú entero. Apenas estoy empezando y se me hace un tanto difícil, tenganme paciencia please.

```css
   * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #header {
    margin:auto;
    width:415px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   
   ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
   }
   
   .nav > li {
    float:left;
   }
   
   .nav li a {
    background-color:#FE2E2E;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:12px 20px;
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
   }
   
   .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
                                z-index:2;
   }
   
   .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
   
  </style>
```

```html
<div id="header">
   <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Servicios</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Contactos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Publica también  el html con solo los css no se puede hacer mucho

Comment: Perdón, soy nuevo en esta página. Ya insterté el HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que el menú ocupe el 100%:

He añadido a las hijas de las etiquetas `.nav`, que tengan un tamaño del 25% dado que són 4, al ser 4 y medir cada un 25% de ancho sería el 100% de la pantalla.

```
.nav > li {
    float:left;
    width:25%;  //línea añadida
}
```

---

```css
   * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #header {
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   
   ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
   }
   
   .nav > li {
    float:left;
                                width:25%;  //línea añadida
   }
   
   .nav li a {
    background-color:#FE2E2E;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:12px 20px;
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
   }
   
   .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
                                z-index:2;
   }
   
   .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
   
  </style>
```

```html
<div id="header">
   <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Servicios</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Contactos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

> Para este código lo que acabo de hacer que es añadir una línea está
>   bien, pero procura utilizar `min-width` y `max-width` cada vez que
>   utilices el porcentaje.

Answer (score 0):

Su utilizas flex-box tendrás un menú que se adapta a cualquier tamaño de pantalla.

Las líneas de código que he incluido son las siguientes.

```
.nav{
display: flex;    
 }

.nav > li{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#header {
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav{
    display: flex;    
}

.nav > li{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li a {
    background-color:#FE2E2E;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:12px 20px;
    display:block;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
}

.nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:140px;
                    z-index:2;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

.nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
}

.nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Servicios</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Contactos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu4</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Acerca de</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Submenu4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```